# How to test suspend function using MockK?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mockk

I am writing a unit test for my Datarepository layer which simply calls an interface.
I am using Kotlin, coroutines and MockK for unit testing.
In MockK, how can I verify that I have called `apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi()` and has happened only once?
Should I put the code in runBlocking?

This is my code:

UnitTest

```
import com.example.breakingbad.api.ApiServiceInterface
import com.example.breakingbad.data.DataRepository
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.InjectMockKs
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.MockK
import io.mockk.verify
import org.junit.Test
```

Repository

```
class DataRepositoryTest {
    @MockK
    private lateinit var apiServiceInterface: ApiServiceInterface

    @InjectMockKs
    private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository

    @Test
    fun getCharacters() {
            val respose = dataRepository.getCharacters()
            verify { apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi() }
    }
}

    class DataRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val apiServiceInterface: ApiServiceInterface
) {
    suspend fun getCharacters(): Result<ArrayList<Character>> = kotlin.runCatching{
        apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi()
    }
}
```

Interface

```
interface ApiServiceInterface {
    @GET("api/characters")
    suspend fun getDataFromApi(): ArrayList<Character>
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I think you should prefer using `runTest` instead of `runBlocking` or `runBlockingTest`.To tell you in brief about the three.

1. `runBlocking` allows you to call suspend functions by blocking a new coroutine and it blocks the current thread until it is completed.
2. `runBlockingTest` will immediately execute the suspending function skipping past any delay and enter coroutine block immediately unlike `runBlocking` which will wait for the amount of the delay

Since kotlinx.coroutines 1.6.0 release, `runBlockingTest` is deprecated in favour of `runTest` [due to these reasons listed in the migration guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md#replace-runblockingtest-with-runtestunconfinedtestdispatcher).

3. `runTest()` will automatically skip calls to delay() and handle uncaught exceptions. [Unlike runBlockingTest() , it will wait for asynchronous callbacks to handle situations where some code runs in dispatchers that are not integrated with the test module.](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/introducing-kotlinx-coroutines-1-6-0/#kotlinx-coroutines-test-update)

I hope that answers your question of what to choose among these 3 to test your suspending function. You code would look like this -:

```
@Test
fun getCharacters() = runTest {
    val response = dataRepository.getCharacters()
    
    coVerify { apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi() }
}
```

Also note that as David mentioned above, because getDataFromApi() is asynchronous/suspending function as well, you will have to use coVerify instead of verify to mock the same.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should put the `dataRepository.getCharacters()` call in a `runBlocking`.

And the `verify` should be replaced for `coVerify`.

In the end, the test should look like this:

```
@Test
fun getCharacters() {
    val respose = runBlocking { dataRepository.getCharacters() }
    
    coVerify { apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi() }
}
```

Also, since you want to verify it has happened only once, you need to call `coVerify` with the *exactly* parameter `coVerify(exactly = 1)`